# Jquery assigning variable name

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of buttons that all use the same `.click()`method. How can I assign a local jquery variable to the `id` of the button that was clicked?

```
var $??? = e.target;
```

What I am trying to do is get the text of the button.

Thanks

Comment: That's _Javascript_.  And your question makes very little sense.

Comment: There's no such thing as a *"jquery variable"*. There's just variables. What does `$???` represent? Are you saying you want the actual variable identifier name to be dynamic, based on the button id?

Comment: @amnotiam haha! hes asking us what `???` should be in that line.

Comment: @Dave: You mean he's asking for advice on the best name for a variable?

Comment: Ok the question was worded badly. @Joseph Marikle's answer worked.

Comment: yes the name & type of variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use what you have there

```
var target = e.target;
$(target).hide(); // or whatever
```

and to get the text

```
var text = $(target).text();
```

EDIT:

or... use `this`

```
var text = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).attr('id')` inside the click handler to get the clicked element's ID, or `$(this).text()` for the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
var self = this;
 $('#myElement').click(function() {
 // here you can use 'self' to reference
 // the enclosing object
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = e.target.id;
```

Or

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```